# Inside Flutter, copy large file from Assets Folder to Application Documents Folder

Tags: android, ios, file, dart, flutter

I try to use a large db-file. And therefore, my code copies this file from the Assets folder to the Application-Documents-Folder as can be seen in the code-example below.

For small files, my code works perfectly fine and I can work with my DB perfectly fine.

However, if I try it with a large db-File (>665MB), things start to break as for my Android-part of my Flutter app. (in fact, iOS works perfectly fine, no matter how large the db-File really is....). Only for Android, a large db-File breaks things.

The following Dart code does not work for a large File (>665MB) inside Android - (however it works for small files):

```dart
  Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {

    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var dbPath = join(directory.path, "ch_departures.db");

    // copy db file from Assets folder to Documents folder (only if not already there...)    
    if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(dbPath) == FileSystemEntityType.notFound) {
     ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/ch_departures.db");
     writeToFile(data, dbPath);
    }

    // Open/create the database at a given path
    var departuresDatabase = await openDatabase(dbPath);
    return departuresDatabase;
  }

  // HERE IS WHERE THE CODE CRASHES (WHEN TRYING TO WRITE THE LOADED BYTES)
  void writeToFile(ByteData data, String path) {
    final buffer = data.buffer;
    return new File(path).writeAsBytesSync(
      buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes));
  }
```

I tried to play around with the `gradle.properties` File of the Android part of my Flutter App.

Inside gradle.properties, I tried:

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m`

But unfortunately, no success.

Do you have any idea on how to make all this work with a large (>665MB) File ????

Comment: How does it fail? Any error message?

Comment: nope - no error message at all !! Complete crash without any message, unfortunately....

Comment: I also tried native Plugins. I succeeded for iOS (since I know Swift) - but I don't know how to do it in Kotlin for the native Android part... But I think, such a simple file-copy should work in Flutter (not going the path with native code), shouldn't it ? Other than the Assets folder, is there any way, I can give a File directly to the Binary and afterwards access it from both Flutter Apps (i.e. iOS and Android) - i.e. without having to copy it from Assets folder to Application Documents Folder ???

Comment: If all my ideas don't work - what would the native Kotlin code look like to make an Asset-File being copied to the Application Documents Folder in an Android native Plugin ?

Comment: https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#sharing-assets-with-the-underlying-platform provides some information about how to make assets available to the native platform. I can imagine the issue is caused by the huge memory usage. The whole file is read into memory and then written back. It would be better to read as stream and forward the stream to the destination file or use some OS copy function.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right. I most likely need to invest more time in the Kotlin aspect of the Android-native FileStream-like copying of the large-file. I was just hoping, somebody knowing Flutter really really well knew how to do that in Dart without the somewhat tedious workaround with the native Plugins. But, I guess, sometimes the world is evolving to slow for my taste :) :)....

Comment: What I miss is a `Stream<int> AssetBundle.readBytes`. That would solve the issue. It might still not be as efficient as calling an Android API to copy a file but it would probably at least not crash.

Comment: hmm, yes. This is missing, still..

Answer (score 1):

There is finally a solution to this large-File copy issue of Flutter that I was experiencing. I created a Flutter plugin that makes the file-copy natively in iOS and Android respectively.

[The Flutter plugin is called `large_file_copy` and can be found here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/large_file_copy).

Comment: This looks like it would be a perfect solution for me, but I'm getting an error building my project:  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher. The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version: project ':large_file_copy' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71.  Do you have an update available?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that copying a large SQLite file to the app document folder from the asset directory.
I couldn't find any good solution.

So I ended up shrinking the size of the SQLite by zipping. Then I copied the zipped file to the app document directory and extracted the database.
If you have a large file in the asset directory, you can zip it into split files and copy them one by one with the "writeToFile" function...